# How to use several aggregate functions at once in Rails/ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to do several aggregate functions at once, eg to get the max and min id's grouped by status:

```
Model.maximum(:id).minimum(:id).group(:status)
```

This doesnt work (at least with Rails 3.1.1) - you get an error on the minimum call, saying its not defined on Fixnum.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `minimum' for 22377:Fixnum
```

I could do raw sql for it - but just wondering if there is a higher level/Rails option...

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe @topek is right that you can't chain the calculation functions like this. I think you'll have to use SQL in a `select` predicate, e.g.:

```
Model.select('MAX(id) AS `maximum`, MIN(id) AS `minimum`').group(:status)
```

I just tested this in a project of my own and it appears to work as expected.

Comment: That looks better to me - nice.

Comment: FWIW, this answer didn't work for me but [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643389/199712) did.

Answer (score 32):

I've had a similar issue which I solved using group with pluck in Rails 4. E.g.

```
Model.group(:status).pluck('min(id)','max(id)')
```

Also works with having, order etc and with computed columns.

```
Model.group('CAST(created_at AS Date), EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at), floor(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM created_at)/15) * 15')
     .having('count(id) > 10')
     .order('min(created_at)')
     .pluck('count(id)')
```

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible with these aggregate functions, because they return a value and not a scope, see the [docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html). They all use the calculate method, which as you can see returns a number:

```
     # File lib/active_record/calculations.rb, line 117
117:       def calculate(operation, column_name, options = {})
118:         validate_calculation_options(operation, options)
119:         column_name     = options[:select] if options[:select]
120:         column_name     = '*' if column_name == :all
121:         column          = column_for column_name
122:         catch :invalid_query do
123:           if options[:group]
124:             return execute_grouped_calculation(operation, column_name, column, options)
125:           else
126:             return execute_simple_calculation(operation, column_name, column, options)
127:           end
128:         end
129:         0
130:       end
```

If you want to do this, you have to craft the query by hand.

Here is an example:

```
sql = "SELECT max(id) as max_id,
              min(id) as min_id
         FROM model
       GROUP
           BY status
    "
Model.find_by_sql(sql).each do |row|
  puts "min. id: #{row.min_id}, " << 
       "max. id: #{row.max_id}, "
end
```